# BLE long-term background scanning working terribly

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want my Android app to scan for BLE peripherals in the background indefinitely.

NOTE: What I'm trying to achieve is the equivalent of using iOS state preservation and restoration - which is working perfectly for me. Even if the system suspends, dozes (Android), or removes the app from memory, I want to pick up advertisements.

My entire BLE callback system is working perfectly if a peripheral is discovered. The issue is, after a few minutes of being backgrounded (5 on some devices), advertisements aren't seen anymore. I can tell because I'm hacked together a little real-time tool to see when discoveries happen.

## Things I have tried

1. Creating a service and promoting it to a foreground service

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataCollectionService.class);
   startService(intent);

   //... and then from the service itself...

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

       builder
           .setContentTitle("Adrich is running.")
           .setContentText("You're all set. Keep an eye on your email inbox for sweet discounts.")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.adrich_android_notify_icon);

       startForeground(1, builder.build());
   }
   ```
2. I have also tried (but then removed) a timer system that restarts BLE after 10 seconds or so. I had read that after [Android 7.0, BLE stops after 30 minutes](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/526).

The thing here is, my background scanning stops after like 5 minutes.

## Question

I'm worried that I'm missing something really obvious here, since background scanning is working so poorly. Any recommendations? What things can I try to get BLE background scanning to work better?

Comment: I assume you use a filtered scan. Which phones/os versions have you tried this on? Same behavior on all phones? Does the Android HCI log or logcat show something interesting (like the scan stops)?

Comment: @Emil I've tried this on many devices (Samsung S8, S6, Xiaomi Note 3 and Note 4, and Motorola E4) and same general behavior. I am using a filtered scan but have also tried unfiltered. Good idea to use logcat though, I'll have to give that a try. Thanks!